# How can I print to the terminal when running a PHP program from an HTTP request?

Tags: php, html

If I run `startIRsend.php` from the comamnd line, it works. If I try to start it from my HTML button the PHP code prints nothing in the terminal.

home.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="startIRsend.php" method="post">
 <input type="submit" value="Run me now!">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

startIRsend.php

```
<?php
echo "hi";
?>
```

Comment: what happens when you click the Run me now! button?

Comment: why do you think something will be printed on the terminal window when you are running the page from a browser?

Comment: @madalinivascu when click on the button the php code is shown

Comment: @madalinivascu If I start directly the php with sudo php startIRsend.php in the terminal I see the output "hi", I think it is the same if I start the php code from an html command. isn't it?

Comment: when you call `startIRsend.php` from the browser you will get the result in the browser not in the terminal

Comment: What is the relationship between the terminal and the HTTP server the browser is making the request to?

Comment: _when click on the button the PHP code is shown_ You are sure you are making the req to the web server and not the file? I mean to the localhost. Do `localhost/startIRsend.php` in the url

Comment: "same if I start the php code from an html command" ...no. I'm not sure where you got this idea from? What will usually happen in this case is the PHP interpreter will be executed by the webserver (e.g. Apache) and will return the response back to the webserver, which will then forward it back to the browser. That's how PHP is used as the backend for web applications. If you want, you could get the PHP code to also log things elsewhere (e.g. to disk or database, but not to a live terminal (and anyway it would be located on the server machine, not the machine where the browser is running)).

Comment: However if you are simply seeing the PHP code listed in the browser (instead of seeing the output of executing the PHP), then this suggests that PHP and the webserver are not properly set up to handle HTTP requests in this way. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page) for relevant information about setting this up correctly.